# pxssh Breaks When ssh Password Is Incorrect

Tags: python, ssh

I Am Trying To Connect to an ssh server in python using pxssh lib

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pxssh

attempt = pxssh.pxssh()

if not attempt.login(IP, USERNAME, PASSWORD):

    print("SSH LOGIN FAILED USING USERNAME : " + USERNAME + " AND PASSWORD : " + PASSWORD)

else:

    print("LOGIN WAS SUCCESSFUL USING USERNAME : " + USERNAME + " AND PASSWORD : " + PASSWORD)

    attempt.sendline("pwd")

    attempt.prompt()

    print attempt.before

break
```

it works fine when password is correct and logs into server and executes

```
pwd
```

but when password is incorrect or login failes for any reason the program breaks i expect this :

```
print("SSH LOGIN FAILED USING USERNAME : " + USERNAME + " AND PASSWORD : " + PASSWORD)
```

but instead i get this error:

```
  File "./ssh.py", line 19, in <module>
    if not attempt.login(IP, USERNAME, PASSWORD):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/pxssh.py", line 292, in login
    raise ExceptionPxssh ('password refused')
pexpect.pxssh.ExceptionPxssh: password refused
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it raises an exception when the password is incorrect, then you have to catch the exception rather than rely on a return value.

Return values and exceptions are two totally different paradigms in dealing with potential error conditions.

As to how to catch exceptions, see https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html for the canonical guide.